# Emacs org-roam - Template needs to specify ':target'

Tags: org-roam

I've been using org-journal, one file per year, and I like it a lot. But I understand if I were to switch to using dailies in org-roam, I'd be able to link to all my other notes/nodes. I'm not sure that will be useful, but I want to try it to see where it goes.

I am getting the error that is in the title of this post when I M-x org-roam-dailies-capture-today. Here is the code I'm using, using the org-roam manual section 12.1.

```
(use-package org-roam
  :after org
  :hook
  (after-init . org-roam-mode)
  :custom
  (org-roam-directory "~/org/roam/")
  (org-roam-completion-everywhere t)
  (org-roam-completion-system 'default)
  (org-roam-dailies-directory "Journal/")
  (org-roam-dailies-capture-templates
    '(("d" "default" entry
       #'org-roam-capture--get-point
       "* %?"
       :target (file+name "Journal/%<%Y-%m-%d>"
                          "#+title: %<%Y-%m-%d %a>\n\n[[roam:%<%Y-%B>]]\n\n")))))
```

Does anyone see the error of my ways?

Comment: `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, then try it again and add the backtrace to your question. I cannot find the variable `org-roam-dailies-capture-templates` (do I need additional packages?) but the doc for `org-roam-capture-templates`does not mention `file+name` in the list of types that a target can be set to. Maybe it should be `file+head`?

Comment: Thank you. I changed to file+head. Didn't fix the problem but clearly needed to be corrected, thank you. I enabled debug and all that happened was "Debug on Error enabled globally
user-error: Template needs to specify ‘:target’" appeared in the messages window.

Comment: You would probably need org-roam to see org-roam-capture-templates.

Comment: I have `org-roam` installed and I can see `org-roam-capture-templates` - what I cannot see is `org-roam-dailies-capture-templates`.

Comment: IOW, maybe you are using the wrong variable in your snippet above.

Comment: I have this as a result of C-h v...org-roam-dailies-capture-templates is a variable defined in ‘org-roam-dailies.el’.

Its value is
(("d" "default" entry "* %?" :target (file+head "%<%Y-%m-%d>.org" "#+title: %<%Y-%m-%d>
")))

Capture templates for daily-notes in Org-roam.
Note that for daily files to show up in the calendar, they have to be of format
"org-time-string.org".
See ‘org-roam-capture-templates’ for the template documentation.

  You can customize this variable.

Comment: How can I get line feeds in a comment? What I have above is impossible to read - and I'm the one who wrote it.

Comment: That's OK - I can read it (and I don't think you can get line feeds in a comment). I'll have to go looking for `org-roam-dailies.el` and install that.

Comment: Hey - it's actually working. The setq was what was needed. I can add notes, and they are concatenated to the daily file. What do I need to do here to thank you for your help?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean (I don't see a `setq` above), but if it's working, who can argue with that? :-)

Comment: Here's what I'm currently using. I've added putting time for each new entry. The thing that finally made it work was using a ` instead of a '. That is backtick instead of single quote.   (org-roam-dailies-capture-templates
          `(("d" "default" entry "\n* %<%I:%M %p>: %?"
             :target (file+head "%<%Y-%m-%d>.org" "#+TITLE: %<%Y-%m-%d %A | week %W | day %j>\n"))))